# Permalinks for Custom Post Type with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, permalinks, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called *products*, which I am rewriting as store, I have registered a hierarchical taxonomy to products called products *product-categories*.

I would like my permalinks to look like.

```
mysite.com/store/cat-name/post-name
```

so permalink structure would look something like..

```
&post_type&/%taxonomy_name%/%post_name%
```

Is there a way to do this in Wordpress 3.1? I'm running the latest release candidate.

I can get to *mysite.com.store/post-name* right now with

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'store')
```

when I register my custom post type

Answer (score 1):

The [custom post permalinks plugin](http://www.johnpbloch.com/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/) solved this for me.